# Fasting on the 15th of Av

Tags: halacha, fast-days, 15th-of-av

There are many days out of the year where one is not allowed to fast (for various reasons. This is my reason for asking by Tu B'Av simply because I don't know and it is a "special" day that we don't say tachnun on.)

Is one allowed to fast on Tu B'Av? Why or why not? Where does it speak about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would think one may not fast on Tu B'Av, but all I have to go on is [this OU article](http://www.ou.org/chagim/roshchodesh/av/tubav.htm) that says a bride and groom don't fast if they get married on the 15th of Av.

> Nowadays, on the Fifteenth of Av, we observe a partial holiday; we don't say "Tachanun," a daily plea for Divine mercy, on the day itself, nor even in the Afternoon Service of the day preceding the fifteenth, similar to a full-scale holiday. Bride and groom also do not fast if the fifteenth is the day of their marriage.

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 573) rules that on all the dates recorded in Megillat Taanit (a compendium of Second Temple minor holidays upon which fasting was prohibited) one nowadays may fast, with the exception of Chanukkah and Purim. [15 Av is included on this list](http://www.tsel.org/torah/megtan/av.html) so nowadays it should revert to being permitted to fast. However, Magen Avraham (OC 573 sk 1) says that since the custom is to treat 15 Av as a holiday nowadays and this is a recorded already in the Gemara, one should not fast on 15 Av. It seems to me he is saying this on the level of *minhag* and not as an actual rabbinic prohibition.